# Equivalence in a complimented distributive lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm stuck at this one. How to prove a given relation is an equivalence relation in a complemented distributive lattice? How to proceed with this?

Q. Show that in a complemented distributive lattice, the following are equivalent.

(i) a≼b (ii) a∧b'=0   (iii) a'∨b=1  (iv) b'≼a'

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: The question is not about proving that a given relation is an equivalence relation; it's about proving that some statements are equivalent.

Comment: apparently, I was able to solve the question thanks @C-RAM for that post it's actually insightful. I'll add the solution in few days,